# Use JOOQ fetch(RecordMapper mapper) got NullPointerException

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to use jooq fetch() to retrieve a list. Something like this

```
sqlQuery.fetch(_sqlToDomainMapper);
```

What happens when there is no matching record? According to javaDoc, the result will never be null, should it be an empty list?

My query goes like

```
SelectOnConditionStep<Record> sqlQuery = _dsl
    .select()
    .from(mytable)
    .leftJoin(state1).on(mytable.id.eq(state1.id))
    .leftJoin(state2).on(mytable.id.eq(state2.id))
    .where(mytable.field1.eq("asdasd"));
sqlQuery.fetch(_sqlToDomainMapper);
```

The mapper builds the domain object from its database representation.

Any pointer would be appreciated! Thank you!

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.business.repositories.exceptions.FailToFetchTopologyRecordException: Failed to query topology records.

        at com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.repositories.sql.SQLTopologyRecordRepository.findTopologyRecords(SQLTopologyRecordRepository.java:184) ~[unified-topology-impl-2.6.172.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.business.service.TopologyRecordServiceV2.findTopologyRecordsByApplication(TopologyRecordServiceV2.java:176) ~[unified-topology-impl-2.6.172.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.restli.TopologyRecordResource.findByApplication(TopologyRecordResource.java:438) ~[unified-topology-impl-2.6.172.jar:?]

        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor37.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.RestLiMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RestLiMethodInvoker.java:143) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.RestLiMethodInvoker.invoke(RestLiMethodInvoker.java:333) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.FilterChainDispatcherImpl.onRequestSuccess(FilterChainDispatcherImpl.java:47) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:86) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]

        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChain.onRequest(RestLiFilterChain.java:55) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.BaseRestLiServer.handleResourceRequest(BaseRestLiServer.java:270) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.RestRestLiServer.handleResourceRequestWithRestLiResponse(RestRestLiServer.java:294) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.RestRestLiServer.handleResourceRequest(RestRestLiServer.java:262) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.RestRestLiServer.handleResourceRequest(RestRestLiServer.java:232) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.RestRestLiServer.doHandleRequest(RestRestLiServer.java:215) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.RestRestLiServer.handleRequest(RestRestLiServer.java:171) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServer.handleRequest(RestLiServer.java:132) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.transport.common.StreamRequestHandlerAdapter$1.onSuccess(StreamRequestHandlerAdapter.java:41) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.transport.common.StreamRequestHandlerAdapter$1.onSuccess(StreamRequestHandlerAdapter.java:31) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.Messages$1.onSuccess(Messages.java:55) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.Messages$1.onSuccess(Messages.java:44) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.FullEntityReader.onDone(FullEntityReader.java:42) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericReader.onDone(ByteStringToGenericReader.java:64) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.entitystream.EntityStreamImpl$WriteHandleImpl.done(EntityStreamImpl.java:276) ~[entity-stream-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericWriter$1.done(ByteStringToGenericWriter.java:51) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.BaseConnector.onDone(BaseConnector.java:60) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericReader.onDone(ByteStringToGenericReader.java:64) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.entitystream.EntityStreamImpl$WriteHandleImpl.done(EntityStreamImpl.java:276) ~[entity-stream-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericWriter$1.done(ByteStringToGenericWriter.java:51) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.ICFilterHelperImpl.lambda$runWithExecutionContext$1(ICFilterHelperImpl.java:183) ~[container-servicecall-filter-impl-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.IC1ExecutionContextPropagator$IC1CallableDecorator.call(IC1ExecutionContextPropagator.java:60) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.IC1ExecutionContextPropagator.call(IC1ExecutionContextPropagator.java:33) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.ExecutionContextManagerImpl$1.call(ExecutionContextManagerImpl.java:118) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at io.grpc.Context.call(Context.java:551) ~[grpc-context-1.46.0.jar:1.46.0]

        at com.linkedin.opentelemetry.context.IoContextPropagator$IoExecutionContext.call(IoContextPropagator.java:40) ~[opentelemetry-sdk-context-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.opentelemetry.context.IoContextPropagator.call(IoContextPropagator.java:26) ~[opentelemetry-sdk-context-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.ExecutionContextManagerImpl$1.call(ExecutionContextManagerImpl.java:118) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.DefaultExecutionContextPropagator$MDCCallableDecorator.call(DefaultExecutionContextPropagator.java:100) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.ic2.internal.ThreadLocalICManager.callWithIC(ThreadLocalICManager.java:94) ~[container-ic-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.DefaultExecutionContextPropagator.call(DefaultExecutionContextPropagator.java:45) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.ExecutionContextManagerImpl$1.call(ExecutionContextManagerImpl.java:118) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.ExecutionContextManagerImpl.call(ExecutionContextManagerImpl.java:76) ~[container-servicecall-impl-1.3.46.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.container.servicecall.internal.ICFilterHelperImpl.runWithExecutionContext(ICFilterHelperImpl.java:182) ~[container-servicecall-filter-impl-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.filter.ic.RestoreOnWriteConnector.tryRestoreAndRun(RestoreOnWriteConnector.java:54) ~[pegasus-r2-impl-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.filter.ic.RestoreOnWriteConnector.access$000(RestoreOnWriteConnector.java:19) ~[pegasus-r2-impl-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.filter.ic.RestoreOnWriteConnector$1.done(RestoreOnWriteConnector.java:36) ~[pegasus-r2-impl-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.BaseConnector.onDone(BaseConnector.java:60) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericReader.onDone(ByteStringToGenericReader.java:64) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.entitystream.EntityStreamImpl$WriteHandleImpl.done(EntityStreamImpl.java:276) ~[entity-stream-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericWriter$1.done(ByteStringToGenericWriter.java:51) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.BaseConnector.onDone(BaseConnector.java:60) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericReader.onDone(ByteStringToGenericReader.java:64) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.entitystream.EntityStreamImpl$WriteHandleImpl.done(EntityStreamImpl.java:276) ~[entity-stream-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.message.stream.entitystream.adapter.ByteStringToGenericWriter$1.done(ByteStringToGenericWriter.java:51) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.transport.http.server.SyncIOHandler.eventLoop(SyncIOHandler.java:198) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.transport.http.server.SyncIOHandler.loop(SyncIOHandler.java:135) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at com.linkedin.r2.transport.http.server.AbstractR2StreamServlet.service(AbstractR2StreamServlet.java:94) ~[r2-core-29.0.1.jar:?]

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.factory.AnnouncingServlet.service(AnnouncingServlet.java:72) ~[pegasus-restli-server-factory-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]

        at org.xeril.util.servlet.LastAccessTimeServletWrapper.service(LastAccessTimeServletWrapper.java:41) ~[util-servlet-27.2.7.jar:?]

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]

        at com.linkedin.restli.server.factory.RestliFactoryServlet.service(RestliFactoryServlet.java:30) ~[pegasus-restli-server-factory-38.7.86.jar:?]

        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:857) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.emweb.ContextBasedHandlerImpl.handle(ContextBasedHandlerImpl.java:73) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.emweb.MapBasedHandlerImpl.handle(MapBasedHandlerImpl.java:480) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:411) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:305) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) ~[?:?]

        at com.linkedin.emweb.ThreadPoolWithTracking$QueuedRunnable.run(ThreadPoolWithTracking.java:424) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) ~[?:?]

        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) ~[?:?]

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jooq_3.14.4.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.Tools.renderAndBind(Tools.java:2420) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SQLImpl.accept(SQLImpl.java:66) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:612) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:270) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SQLCondition.accept(SQLCondition.java:67) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:612) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:270) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.CombinedCondition.accept(CombinedCondition.java:214) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:612) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:270) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.ConditionProviderImpl.accept(ConditionProviderImpl.java:129) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:612) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:270) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReference0(SelectQueryImpl.java:2056) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.toSQLReferenceLimitDefault(SelectQueryImpl.java:1566) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.accept0(SelectQueryImpl.java:1459) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SelectQueryImpl.accept(SelectQueryImpl.java:1233) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.DefaultRenderContext.visit0(DefaultRenderContext.java:612) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:270) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.getSQL0(AbstractQuery.java:534) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:330) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:333) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:1560) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:3951) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.repositories.sql.SQLTopologyRecordRepository.findTopologyRecords(SQLTopologyRecordRepository.java:181) ~[unified-topology-impl-2.6.178.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.business.service.TopologyRecordServiceV2.findTopologyRecordsByApplication(TopologyRecordServiceV2.java:176) ~[unified-topology-impl-2.6.178.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.unifiedtopology.impl.restli.TopologyRecordResource.findByApplication(TopologyRecordResource.java:438) ~[unified-topology-impl-2.6.178.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.RestLiMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RestLiMethodInvoker.java:143) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.RestLiMethodInvoker.invoke(RestLiMethodInvoker.java:333) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.FilterChainDispatcherImpl.onRequestSuccess(FilterChainDispatcherImpl.java:47) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:86) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108) ~[?:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.onRequest(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:72) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at com.linkedin.restli.internal.server.filter.RestLiFilterChainIterator.lambda$onRequest$0(RestLiFilterChainIterator.java:73) ~[restli-server-29.0.1.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace of your exception?

Comment: Thank you! Stack trace: justpaste.it/8756t The line that throws the exception is return queryHelper.buildQuery().fetch(_sqlToDomainMapper); 

The queryHelper builds the sql query.

Comment: You can edit the question and paste the stack trace directly here. However, the interesting bits have been truncated, i.e. the parts following `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks, updated. @LukasEder Unfortunately the null pointer was all i see in the logs. In terms of jooq behavior, if no matching record found does sqlQuery.fetch(_sqlToDomainMapper); return an empty list?

Comment: Found more logs from jooq

Comment: Your stack trace doesn't seem to match the query you've shown. There's a `SQLCondition`, which means you're using a plain SQL template. But the only way this particular line `Tools.renderAndBind(Tools.java:2420) ~[jooq-3.14.4.jar:?]` can throw a NPE is when you pass it a `null` SQL string. Maybe, that could be intercepted earlier, but there's clearly a bug in your code, which you haven't shown here yet...